# Exibindo mensagens de erro em uma aplicação web

Tags: java, java-ee, exceção

Desenvolvi uma aplicação web simples para estudar alguns conceitos relacionados a `Servlet` dentre outros. Mapeei o arquivo `web.xml` de minha aplicação para exibir uma `página de erro` caso alguma exceção ocorra.

**Dúvida:** qual a melhor de forma de exibir as exceções para esse caso específico? É correto pegar as exceções e customizar suas mensagens como no exemplo abaixo?

**Para uma falha na conexão com o banco de dados:**

```
public Connection getConnection() {
     try {
         DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
         return DriverManager.getConnection(
                 "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB", "root", "");
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         throw new ConnectionException("Falha na conexão com o banco de dados");
     }
}
```

**Existe uma boa prática quanto à apresentação de mensagens de erro ao usuário?**

**EDIT**

Eis a minha página tratadora de erros (meio tolinha ainda, mas aguardando uma ajuda para se tornar mais séria):

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Falha do sistema</h1>
Descrição: ${pageContext.errorData.throwable.message}
</body>
</html>
```

Nesse caso, `(1)`vou precisar dar try/catch sempre de modo a customizar a mensagem da exceção (throw new MinhaException("Minha mensagem"))? `(2)`De que forma eu posso tornar minhas mensagens dinâmicas sem precisar dar try/catch? `(3)`Existe alguma forma de eu interceptar as exceçoes e apresentar uma mensagem diferente para cada tipo?

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** importante perceber que a dúvida surge a partir do uso da variável `${pageContext.errorData.throwable.message}` para imprimir o erro.

Answer (score 3):

É tudo uma questão de bom senso, Geison. Não sei se entendi exatamente sua pergunta, mas vamos por partes.

> qual a melhor de forma de exibir as exceções para esse caso
>   específico? É correto pegar as exceções e customizar suas mensagens
>   como no exemplo abaixo?

Talvez uma mensagem de erro na conexão com o banco não seja interessante para o usuário. Ele não quer saber tecnicamente o que aconteceu, muita gente nem sabe o que é um banco de dados, por exemplo. Então, em termos de log de erro da aplicação, o quanto mais específico ele for, melhor, pois nós desenvolvedores temos acesso a ele. No que diz respeito a o que vai aparecer para o usuário temos que avaliar o seguinte: *é um erro que deveria ser tratado ou um "engasgo", um erro não esperado?*

No primeiro caso, no início de um desenvolvimento, geralmente não temos todos os possíveis erros. Até o tratamento de exceção passa por um período de maturidade durante o desenvolvimento de software. Conforme vamos desenvolvendo e nos deparando com erros, o tratamos e o usuário tem assim uma mensagem de erro amigável, seja ela de um campo obrigatório não preenchido ou uma regra de negócio não cumprida. Esse tipo de mensagem geralmente deve ser exibida com destaque na tela que o usuário está.

No segundo caso, o que particularmente faço, é tratar como "erro fatal". Exibo uma tela de erro padrão do sistema.

De forma geral, tenho um tipo de exceção para o sistema, a qual uso para "mapear" os erros conhecidos, que devem ser tratados. Numa barreira de exceção eu capturo esse tipo de exceção e exibo para o usuário. Qualquer outra exceção que ainda seja desconhecida ou seja fruto de um "engasgo" do sistema, é exibida numa tela exclusiva de erro.

Consegui esclarecer sua dúvida?

Abraços,

Comment: Pimenta vou editar minha pergunta para ficar mais claro o que quero. Acho que minha pergunta ficou muito superficial.

Comment: @GeisonSantos, como você quer lançar exceções não é necessário fazer o try/catch, você pode simplesmente, onde for necessário, lançar sua exceção `throw new MinhaExcecao("Minha mensagem!")`. Se ela for _checked_, você vai ter que em algum momento usar o try/catch, caso contrário não vai precisar.
Você pode criar um filtro servlet pra interceptar suas exceções e tratá-las do jeito que quiser ou, se resolver, usar a tag `<error-page>` no _web.xml_, na qual você tem as opções de mapear um erro pelo código `<error-code>` ou tipo `<exception-type>` e chamar uma _jsp_ ou outro servlet `<location>`.

Comment: "Você pode criar um filtro servlet pra interceptar suas exceções e tratá-las do jeito que quiser." @Pimenta, você pode me dar um exemplo dessa abordagem? Melhor, você  pode adicionar na sua resposta. Aí eu fecho o tópico como resolvido.